# Spotify API get track_uri or track_id from own spotify data

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spotify

[enter image description here][1]I have a dataframe that included my own data I've requested from Spotify (https://www.spotify.com/de/account/privacy/) Now, I have .json data, that I've converted to .csv, that is my StreamingHistory ( incl msplayed, timestamp, artist, trackName). I'd like to add the track_id or uri to the dataframe. Is that possible to a match of the trackName and artistName with the Spotify API? Because the API is kind of complex for me now.

Now I'd like to add a new column with the uri/track_id to then get the audio features of the song. As I've said already I don't know if it's possible to get the uri in this way.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2UGh.png

```
CLIENT_ID = '' 
CLIENT_SECRET = ''

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret) 
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

AUTH_URL ="https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
auth_response = requests.post(AUTH_URL, {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
})

#Convert response to JSON
auth_response_data = auth_response.json()

#Save the access token
access_token = auth_response_data['access_token']

#Need to pass access token into header to send properly formed GET request to API server
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}'.format(token=access_token)
}
sp=spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id="CLIENT_ID",client_secret="CLIENT_SECRET"))

BASE_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/'




df.to_csv(StreamingHistoryEditedComplete.csv)

new_df['songArtistID'] = new_df['artistName'] + ":" + new_df['trackName']
```

Comment: please add the input data of the json, or at least a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of it. The link does not help in anything. What have you tried so far ? Have you got already some code?

Comment: see the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2UGh.png @Rabinzel

Comment: did you read the link I showed you? here is a quote: `DO NOT use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then format it as code. This helps others more easily read and test your code.`

Comment: @Rabinzel Thank you. Yes, I have a bit of code but it's not really helpful for the new column I want to add. As I've said, I want to add the track_id to each song. But idk if that is possible with just having the trackName + artist